# Swift Delegate is not being called

Tags: ios, swift

I have completed all the needed code for delegate to work. In  my viewcontroller:
`class ViewController: UIViewControllerCustomViewDelegate`
I also have this:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            let myCustomView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ImageHeaderView", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! ImageHeaderView
        myCustomView.delegate = self

        }
func goToNextScene() {
        print("GOTOSCENE2")
            }
```

And in my custom view I have this:

```
import UIKit

protocol CustomViewDelegate: class {         // make this class protocol so you can create `weak` reference
    func goToNextScene()
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
class ImageHeaderView : UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var followme: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var profileImage : UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundImage : UIImageView!

    weak var delegate: CustomViewDelegate?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: "E0E0E0")
        self.profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = self.profileImage.frame.size.height / 2
        self.profileImage.clipsToBounds = true
        self.profileImage.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.profileImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        //self.profileImage.setRandomDownloadImage(80, height: 80)
        //self.backgroundImage.setRandomDownloadImage(Int(self.frame.size.width), height: 100)
    }
    @IBAction func followme(_ sender: AnyObject) {
         UserDefaults.standard.set(followme.isOn, forKey: "followme")
    }
    @IBAction func logout(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        delegate?.goToNextScene()
        print("GOTOSCENE")
    }
}
```

There is are no errors thrown but when I click/tap the button, nothing happens. It just prints "GOTOSCENE".

Comment: removing weak will not solve the problem. weak only protects the delegate from being accessed after deallocation (i.e. delegate will be nil if the delegate has been freed)

Comment: Isn't myCustomView added to the view? Maybe you have more than one instance?

Comment: I removed class and weak. Still not working.

Comment: @JaysonTamayo try printing delegate before the call

Comment: @giorashc When I remove `?[0]` from the declaration of `myCustomView`, I'm getting a nil. So maybe the problem is in that line.

Comment: I believe Kuntal Gajjar is correct in his answer. You are creating a NEW imageheaderview instance which is not connected to the tap action in the storyboard

Comment: @giorashc I do not know how to add the reference outlet to my view controller.

Comment: I feel that I missing something but I think you are delegating the wrong class "class ViewController: UIViewControllerCustomViewDelegate" should be "class ViewController: CustomViewDelegate" ... I am still with Swift2 so... dont know if something is changed but it use to be that way. Actually it should not work at all write now....

Answer (score 3):

What I feel is

Your problem is right here

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            let myCustomView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ImageHeaderView", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! ImageHeaderView
        myCustomView.delegate = self

        }
```

I think you have added imageHeaderview from storyboard and in viewdidload you are creating new object of ImageHeaderView and assigning delegate to newly created object.

Try to outlet your ImageHeaderView and assign delegate to outleted object.

Hope this will fix your issue.

Comment: I cant seem to drag the ImageViewHeaderView's button to my ViewController

Comment: I am very sorry. I really don't know how to add it. I usually hold CTRL and drag it to the viewcontroller, but it can't seem to add it

Comment: Can you please help me how to create the outlet connection? Thank you.

Comment: ok please post a screenshot of your storyboard I will help you